# How to generate a "log" series of number knowing the start and end?

Tags: statistics, logarithms, graphing-functions

**I'd like to generate a series of number that follow a logarithmic curve style in Google Sheets.** I know it kind of means nothing, but maybe this will help: it's for creating a previsional growth chart. So I know what the curve should look like, but don't know how to create it.

I managed to "create" this one but I'd like to be able to specify the start and end number and, if it's possible, the curve "bending" coefficient.

[image]

I'm then using the values in some other cells in the spreadsheet. The formula for this plot (blue line) is `= 30 + 300 * LN(30 * (COLUMN(A1) - 1) + 1)`, spreaded over multiple cells of the same row.

Pretty much graphic design but using maths as the tool!

---

**EDIT**

I made the Sheet available for anyone interested : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/147rfa4vrlOFYjrm17LZUoxOAtYC6_VdRN3pvNjR8_cg/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: For clarification:  are you saying that you know the initial and final coordinates, and you want to place a log curve between them?

Comment: @D.B. Exactly. Starts at (2018 Q4, 30) and ends at (2020 Q4, 1500).

Comment: @D.B. No data points in between. Just the curve style I want to get (and its corresponding values). If it helps I can provide one data point: 2019 Q1 should be the half of my end point. What would be the easiest formula in your point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose I want to place a log curve between points $(x_0,y_0) and (x_f,y_f)$.  My equation will be of the form:
$$y = a\log(x)+b$$.  If I know two points, there is a unique logarithmic curve joining them.  Your job is to find the numbers $a$ and $b$ which describe this curve.  Then, $y_0 = a\log(x_0)+b$ and $y_f = a\log(x_f)+b$.  This is a system of two equations in two variables.  Note that $y_f-y_0 = a\log(\frac{x_f}{x_0}) \implies a = \frac{y_f-y_0}{\log(x_f/x_0)}$.  After calculating $a$, you can easily find $b$.

Comment: It works perfect, thanks. So I'm maybe not fully aware of the specificities of a log curve, but can the curve "bending" coefficient be adjustable? Maybe by adding a third point?

Comment: I don't know what a bending coefficient is.  But maybe someone else can help you with that.  You could try asking a new question.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but perhaps helpful.

It seems as if what you want is a curve that trends the way your data do, perhaps for prediction.

I would suggest asking your spreadsheet to find that curve.

I suspect the 2018Q4 data point is an anomaly for prediction. I'd leave it out. Then just ask for a logarithmic trendline.

Here's how to do that in Excel

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choosing-the-best-trendline-for-your-data-1bb3c9e7-0280-45b5-9ab0-d0c93161daa8

Google sheets doesn't have that functionality built in, but there are discussions online if you search for *google sheets log trendline* .

Comment: Actually I'd like to have the values on that curve, not only the curve, my question may be misleading. The data you're talking about is loosely generated with the formula I pasted, I'm looking to improve this formula to have more precise values that follow a log curve. These values are then used to calculate other stuff, and then to draw the graph.